# Google Loader does not load all elements from RSS-feed

Tags: javascript, rss, google-loader

I am trying to load the first 6 entries from a RSS news feed using the Google Loader API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("feeds", "1");
function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/aip/prodlog/aktuelles/rssfeed.xml");
    feed.setNumEntries(6);
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            console.log(result.feed.entries);
        }

    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

However, I only get back 5 entries since the second of the first two entries is missing. I assume that this is due to the publishing date of the entries which is the same day for the first two entries (I changed it to test and it eventually shows up - but this is not a solution in the long run...). However, so far I couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue. Any help for this is appreciated.

Comment: The Google Feed API has ben deprecated. You should not use it as it can go down at any point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now use Feednami (https://feednami.com/) which should be future proof and also resolves the issue I originally had..